# How to make a javascript pop-up send me to a .cshtml page?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm kind of new at working with both c# and javascript and i'm not sure how can i open a .cshtml page from a javascript pop-up. So basically i have a map on which i have 2 pins ( for the moment ), which represent parking lots in my city. I want to create a "View details" button in the pop-up which will redirect me to a new page.
Here is mai .cshtml page:

```
@model ProiectColectiv.Models.User
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Admin Map";
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
    html, body, #map-container {
        height: 100%;
    }

    #mapid {
        height: 94vh;
    }

    .header {
        left: 80px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 9vh;
        z-index: 401;
    }
</style>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/map.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.css"
          integrity="sha512-puBpdR0798OZvTTbP4A8Ix/l+A4dHDD0DGqYW6RQ+9jxkRFclaxxQb/SJAWZfWAkuyeQUytO7+7N4QKrDh+drA=="
          crossorigin="" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="header">
        Hello, @Model.Name!
    </h1>
    <div id="mapid"></div>
</body>
</html>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.js"
        integrity="sha512-QVftwZFqvtRNi0ZyCtsznlKSWOStnDORoefr1enyq5mVL4tmKB3S/EnC3rRJcxCPavG10IcrVGSmPh6Qw5lwrg=="
        crossorigin=""></script>

<script>
    var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([46.776, 23.594], 13);

    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
        {
            maxZoom: 18,
            minZoom: 12,
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }).addTo(mymap);

    var marker = L.marker([46.770, 23.592]).addTo(mymap);
    marker.bindPopup("Parcarea Adminului. View Details");
    L.marker([46.7825, 23.6880]).addTo(mymap).bindPopup("Parcarea lu varu!");

</script>
```

My question is, how can i make this connection?
And also, if anyone has any idea if there is any Google Maps API for parking lots in different cities, please let me know.